# Automate a login when login button has no "id" using python

Tags: python, html

[portfolio123.com](https://www.portfolio123.com/app/auth) recently changed their whole website.

When a login submit button has no ID label:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="data.loading">{{ data.loading ? 'Please wait...' : 'Submit' }}</button>
```

how would one do an automated login? (this is how you "normally" do it

```
signInButton = browser.find_element_by_id('signIn')\n",
    "signInButton.click()\n
```

I am trying to do this:
https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/automate-create-login-bot-python-selenium/

Doing a get by class btn btn-primary could work... But there are 4 buttons on this page that use that class...

Did they purposely make this modification so bots cannot get in?

Answer (score 0):

You could use xpath

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Submit"]').click()
```

You can test it identifies the element correctly by pasting the string in to a browser console between $x('') symbols

e.g.

```
>> $x('//button[text()="Submit"]')
```